# Compare search parameter with string

Tags: c#

I know what code I need to change to do this but I am not sure how to change it.

So lets say you input a parameter search of DUA

and your table looks like this

```
Name
-----
Duane
Dakdua
Olpdua
Poduaia
```

what I want this code to do is take the number of letters searched, in this case three, and search it against the first of that number.

So the only result I should be getting is 'Duane'

I inherited this code so I had to dig through it and this is the line I found that I believe I have to change.

```
nameQuery = nameQuery.Where(name => name.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(searchParameter));
```

Comment: There's a `StartsWith` method for string.

Comment: You should use startsWith() instead of contains() for this result

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know that existed.  Please put it in, as an answer so I can thumbs it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a c# method for strings - [StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx), also check out the StringComparison param (so you can ignore case)

your code would look like this:

```
nameQuery = nameQuery.Where(x=> x.FirstName.StartsWith(searchParameter ,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have stated, you want StartsWith:

```
nameQuery = nameQuery.Where(name => name.FirstName
    .StartsWith(searchParameter ,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

I am thinking you may want to return the items in order.

```
nameQuery = nameQuery.Where(name => name.FirstName
    .StartsWith(searchParameter ,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).OrderBy(name => name);
```